Ubuntu Server 22.04 Freezes Completely
I have a relative new system, it worked for about 1 month without issues but starting about 1 week ago it starts to freeze completely. The freeze is so bad I can't do anything, any SysRq and the only thing is to cycle using power button.
Characteristics:

MB: ASUS TUF Gaming Z790-Plus WiFi
CPU: Intel Core i9-14900F Desktop Processor 24 cores
RAM: CORSAIR VENGEANCE DDR5 RAM 96GB (2x48GB) 5600MHz CL40 Intel XMP iCUE
GPU: GIGABYTE GV-N1030D4-2GL GeForce GT 1030 Low Profile D4 2G
Cooling: NZXT Kraken 240 - RL-KN-240-B1 - 240mm AIO CPU Liquid Cooler
HDD: WD_BLACK 2TB SN850X NVMe Internal Gaming SSD Solid State Drive with Heatsink

My assumption is that I'm facing a physical component issue, but not sure which one. I did look into other threads like
Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS freezes randomly and permanently and How do I diagnose my issue, when I'm not sure if it is a hardware or software issue?
but I was unable to either follow the steps (most are Ubuntu Desktop and may have differences as some components I don't have) or they didn't lead me anywhere.
The system seems to act OK when going to Grub -> Root (with network on) as it doesn't crash at all and stays a lot without issues. So one culprit could be the Video card, not sure yet. Also if I keep the system off for like 20 minutes, it tends to stay up for another hour or so, but if it freezes and I try to reboot, many times it freezes instantly. It also froze with Live Ubuntu disk running "normal resolution". It did not freeze (at least not very quickly) with the "Safe graphics" option of "Try Ubuntu"
A few checks already:

Motherboard - no visible issues (popped capacitors or damage)
Motherboard - I updated the BIOS (ASUS using EZ Flash) - issues still persists
CPU - I did the "s-tui" test successfully
CPU - sensors command gives around 35C for all cores
CPU - temperatures on CPU are around 30C, however Asus shows 54 for CPU Package and 40 for Core. The cooling unit has a digital LCD that displays liquid temperature, that shows around 30C all the time
Cleanup - apt update, upgrade, clean, autoremove
RAM - I did create a MemTest86 bootable and did the "Test Memory" which completed with no errors found on all 96 GB RAM
RAM - I did run successfully "memtester 6G 5" though
HDD - nvme smart-log /dev/nvme0n1 - shows no visible signs
HDD - Asus has a smart test in BIOS - ran succesfully
Video - I tried another video card, much older, still freezes.
LOG - /var/crash - empty
LOG - /var/log/syslog - not sure what to look for there...
LOG - /var/log/dmesg - no idea what to look for

One thing I noticed is that while in Bios and while doing root/command prompt actions it never freezes. But once I start Ubuntu in X mode it randomly freezes without any warning...
Any other ideas?

thank you @karel! I will try to take some of the suggestions there one by one. I see some that I tried but also some that I haven't. I wil dig a bit more tonight and post the results.

After a bit of trial and error, I did the following: reinstalled Ubuntu, removed 1 stick of Ram. So far the system works for more than 48 hours now. One interesting thing is that once I installed AnyDesk application it frozed again. So I removed AnyDesk and now it works decently. Aparently one source of the freeze was caused by AnyDesk running on Wayland. Still that doesn't explain why it froze on boot from Live USB.... Maybe the memory removed. So here the question is : is it the memory stick or is it the motherboard rejecting too much RAM... I will still troubleshoot to find a clear answer

After lots of trial and error the system is up for a few days. I did a complete reinstall of Ubuntu with full data wipe on HDD to make sure. Here is the problem(s):

I reinstalled Ubuntu (after a backup) with a full wipe of HDD. This still doesn't explain why it froze while I booted from LIVE USB and in Try Ubuntu, but still, I felt the need to take this off the list

Even if MemTest gave no errors I removed 1 stick of RAM. Now the server runs, temporarily, on just 48 GB RAM. I will check in a few days to see if I replace it with the other stick then it is clear. Or it could be the motherboard (although the RAM was purchased with exact specs from Asus website), but motherboard may be limiting the RAM somehow. Not sure yet.

after installing everything back, as soon as I installed and started AnyDesk on Wayland the froze was back again. I uninstalled AnyDesk and system seems to be running smoothly. I am looking for a remote desktop solution, however AnyDesk doesn't seem to fit, it acts way to agressively. I know it may work on Xorg, still, I am kind of scared to put it back...


So at this time server is up and running. I will come back with edits if I see anything extra. I hope this helps anyone else.
Thank you!
